# Scrapy execution flow

Tags: python, scrapy

i am trying to understand Scrapy execution but getting confused because of the generators used in between.i have little idea on generators but i am not able to visualize/correlate those things in here

below is the code from scrapy documentation

questions

1) How yield works here

2)I see two for loops in **parse** function  ,1st for loop is calling **parse_author** function in the yield but is getting called only after for loop1(executing twice) and loop2(executing once).can some one please explain how the execution flow is happening here.

```
import scrapy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
name = 'prox-reveal'
start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
def parse(self, response):
    # follow links to author pages
    for href in response.css('.author + a::attr(href)'):
        print('1---------->{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S-%f')))
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)

    # follow pagination links
    for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
        print('2---------->{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S-%f')))
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

def parse_author(self, response):
    print('3---------->{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S-%f')))
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

    yield {
        'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
        'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
        'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified overview of the relation between a request and its callback:

- A `Request` object is created and passed to Scrapy's engine for further processing

  ```
  yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)
  ```
- The requested webpage is downloaded and a `Response` object is created
- The request's callback (`parse_author()`) is called with the created response

Now comes the part I believe is causing you trouble.

Scrapy is an asynchronous framework, it can do other things while waiting for I/O operations (such as downloading a webpage) to complete.

So your loop is continued, other requests are created and processed, and the callback will be called - once the data for it is available.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense now. However, I still dint get how yield works. Per my understanding NEXT command should be there for any yield to work.Did I miss something?. Thanks again

Comment: An important thing to know here is that you're only writing a small part of the code that is being executed, while the majority of the details, along with the actual execution of the code, is handled by the framework. So there probably is a `next` (or a for loop) somewhere in the code of scrapy itself.

Comment: @stranac-- True and convinced, thanks a lot.my intention was to request people's help in understanding  something obvious(if any) that I missed.